# Make sure exactly one boolean of a given list is true?

Tags: php, xor, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

If I have the following booleans

```
const YESTERDAY = false;
const TODAY = true;
const TOMORROW = false;
```

What code can I write to make sure exactly one is true?

I've tried this:

```
$x = self::YESTERDAY ^ self::TODAY ^ self::TOMORROW;
```

The problem is that with all three constants set to `true` then `$x` is `true`.

Comment: you could put all the combination using OR condition `(YESTERDAY=true AND TODAY=false AND TOMORROW=false) or (YESTERDAY=false AND TODAY=true AND TOMORROW=false) or (YESTERDAY=false AND TODAY=false AND TOMORROW=true)`

Comment: He need to sure that true is excalty ONE, not AT LEAST ONE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$x = ((int) self::YESTERDAY) + ((int) self::TODAY) + ((int) self::TOMORROW);` Then if `$x === 1;` You've got what you need.

**EDITED:**

Even without type casts `(int)`, it works well, thanks to @DaveRandom, so:

`if (self::YESTERDAY + self::TODAY + self::TOMORROW == 1) {}`, as for me.

Comment: I thought about this but it'd be nice to avoid all that extra processing, is there a bitwise way to do this?

Comment: +1 this - it seems after testing that you don't even need the `(int)` casts, it happens implicitly.

Comment: This is much tidier than any of the other solutions. @Matt was almost correct in using the XOR (^) operator, but unfortunately `true ^ true ^ true` will evaluate to `true`, because PHP interprets it as `(true ^ true) ^ true`, i.e. `false ^ true`

Comment: This an amazing solution. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

The neatest way I can think of is [`array_sum()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
if (array_sum(array(self::YESTERDAY, self::TODAY, self::TOMORROW)) == 1) {
  // Do something
}
```

**EDIT** Actually, all you need to do it replace the `^` with `+` in your original attempt, and it achieves the same thing:

```
$x = self::YESTERDAY + self::TODAY + self::TOMORROW;
```

This turns `$x` into the number of `TRUE` values. So for a boolean output use:

```
$ok = self::YESTERDAY + self::TODAY + self::TOMORROW === 1;
```

Comment: Actually a variation on devdRew's answer is the neatest - if you just replace the `^` with `+` in your original code it does the same thing - you don't need the `(int)` casts as this happens implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to devdRew's answer

```
$x = array_count_values(array((int) self::YESTERDAY,(int) self::TODAY,(int) self::TOMORROW));
if (isset($x[1]) && $x[1] == 1) {
    echo 'Only one TRUE';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over a list of your variables and break when you found a second boolean that is true:

```
$moreThanOneTrue=false;
$oneTrue;
foreach ($BOOL_VAR_ARRAY as $bool) {
    if ($bool) {
        if($oneTrue) {
            $moreThanOneTrue=true;
            break;
        }
        $oneTrue=true;
    }
}
```

Like this it's more handy when you have more than three variables.

Comment: If there's more than 3 I think the `array_sum` method would be simpler than this

Answer (score 0):

x will return true if and only if one is true and others are false.

```
$x = ($a && !($b || $c)) || ($b && !($a || $c)) || ($c && !($a || $b));
```

May be a bad code, but works.

Answer (score 0):

`a ^ b ^ c ^ (a & b & c)` is the expresion you look for.